# Help me to complete my UITableView to Navigation Controller [iPhone SDK]

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I built an application. On the one my views I used TableView. So now I want to change this Table view to a navigation controller.

1- How can I change UITable view to Navigation Controller. I add navigation codes but I got some alert! [I know I must identify my navigation delegate, but HOW ?]
[alt text http://freezpic.com/pics/2925e25b0b869ef954c081d374f366ed.jpg](http://freezpic.com/pics/2925e25b0b869ef954c081d374f366ed.jpg)

Here is my Mapping Views!

AppNameViewController

- FirstViewController   [on this view I used table view and I want change to nav]
- SecondViewController
- ThirdViewControllerController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method do this:

```
FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC];

[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

[secondVC release];
[navigationController release];
```

Answer (score 2):

As Xcode is telling you, there is no such method as `-pushViewController:` on `UINavigationController`. The method you're looking for is `-pushViewController:animated:`, as in

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: oh god i had forgot it :))
but still doesn't work and going to anotherViewController with nav !